# cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have a questions regarding the error "cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied"

I have a brand new laptop, installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and installed
Visual Studio Code
gcloud cloud CLI

I have a NAS where the code is stored. I'm able to browse the NAS -out of the box- to a specific file and open this file in Visual Studio Code. Saving the changed file is no problem at all.

Then I rightclick the directory and select "Open in Terminal"
When I want to perform a "gcloud app deploy" (or a sudo gcloud app deploy) command, I get the message:

cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied

Because I'm able to edit a file in Visual Studio Code, I assume that the rights at the NAS are fine.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Hans

Comment: How did you install that program?

Comment: I used snap. As described at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb :

If you want gcloud and gsutil to automatically update to the latest version and you're running a modern Ubuntu release that uses the Snap Package Manager, you can install the Google Cloud CLI as a snap package.

Comment: Add this information directly to your question: use "edit"